# How to evaluate similarity of datasets based on summary data?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, sample, quantiles, levenes-test

I have summary data that I want to compare to my own data. For the summary data I do not have access to the underlying data, however, I know the percentiles as shown below (A). I also calculated summary data from my own dataset (B). It seems that both datasets are from a similar distribution. Could I use Levene's Test or some other test with summary data to make such argument? If so what test is most useful given the example below? Any ideas?

```
Per. | A   |  B
98%  | 247 | 246
75%  | 48  | 50
50%  | 13  | 17
25%  | 1   | 3
02%  | 0   | 0.001
```

Comment: Please explain what the table is actually showing. What is the value 247? is it a count? A measurement? What is the 98%? Is it a cdf? a survivor function? Something else? Note that Levene's test is irrelevant here; however, there will be things that can be done, but the ones I can think of would use all of your sample.

Comment: The values (247, 246, 48, etc.) are measurements how far people in a population travel in miles. E.g., people in dataset B have a median travel distance of 17 miles. The percentiles (98%, 75%, etc.) are values in a CDF. I should also add that I have further datasets--C and D-- that I want to compare to another (i.e., compare C and D). In C and D the numbers are not similar, but proportional (e.g., at the 98% I have for C 310 miles and for D 30 miles, at the 75% for C 20 miles and for D 18 miles).

Comment: Do you know the sample sizes? Then you can (at least approximately) reconstruct a contingency table, and so use a chi-squared test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it very much. Yes, I know the sample sizes. So, would I just use ranges for the distances? E.g., for set A: 49 to 247 miles, 14 to 48 miles, etc. After all, it is not possible to know the exact distances. Also, would I just assume that my sets follow a Chi Square distribution?